# Processing information from Twitter Search API with PHP or Python

Tags: php, python, json, rest, twitter

I want to be able to order a list of terms by how many results I get in a search query on twitter using each term in the list.

I know that the search API allows me do things like this -->
http://search.twitter.com/search.atom?q=
or
http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=

I can type these into my browser bar and get the appropriate atom/JSON results.

My question is how do I go about writing a script in PHP (preferably) or Python that will grab a list of terms from a database, search for them in real time  or periodically and return the results in a way that enables me go on with my processing.

I am not asking for "coding help" ..I just want to know what tools (e.g. libraries/scripts) are useful for getting started with the problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Get started with extracting data from database and performing request to twitter search API.

Comment: Twitter limits the number of requests you can make to their API. So make sure to cache your calls. You simply call the json URL with CURL and json_decode() it (with PHP)

Comment: @JohnP this is more of an answer than a comment..:) too bad I can't upvote it or select it...

Comment: on mobile and in the move :) will post an answer when I get to my comp

Answer (score 0):

Grab the data using JSON. You won't need any special parsing tools if you use JSON since you can simply call [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) on it. Be aware that this is available only on PHP versions 5.2 and up and that some hosts may have disabled it. You can use cURL to get the contents from the URL or if you have fopen wrappers `on`, you can simply use [file_get_contents()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php)

Once you have the array/object, you'll need to cache it since Twitter limits the number of requests you can make per hour. If you get an API key this limit is increased, but the limitation is still there. So you might want to keep an eye on how many requests are being made per hour.